# Hearing headphone microphone through headphone speakers

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphones

I have got some Sennheiser 4.40BT headphones. When I connect them to my laptop (Windows 10) through bluetooth, then enable the microphone, all sound that goes through the microphone gets relayed through the headphone speakers. It makes everything sound very echoey and I can hear the smallest of sounds really loudly. If I connect the headphones to my laptop through a cable I don't get this issue.

How can I stop the sound going through the microphone being relayed to the speakers?

Comment: I have the exact same problem and it's really infuriating.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but may be worth checking.

Search type "Manage Audio Devices" and select.
The "Sound" window will pop up.
Select "Recording".
Select "Microphone".
Now click on "Properties" at lower right hand location.
Now select "Listen".

Be sure that the box next to "Listen to this device" is not check marked.

Comment: Thanks for replying but the checkbox for "Listen to this device" is not checked.

Comment: Last hope. I had other problems with the sound system. Everything was set correctly, but it was not working properly. This also dealt with the microphone. So I disabled all the recording devices listed, meaning if I disabled one device and another is automatically selected, I disabled it as well until all devices were disabled. I rebooted and then selected the appropriate recording device. All was well after that. The point being is that what you see is selected is not always entirely what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually just the mic picking up the audio. Normally the solution would be to move the mic away from the speakers. This is called feedback: a great thing for guitars, not so much for listening to music.

It is unclear if the audio cable supports mic input: normally a stereo connector with mic support has four conductors (3 black rings). If it does not, then this may be why the problem goes away when wired.

It may also be that the headphones are not powered when connected via the cable and therefore, the mic is not pre-amplified.

Not much of an answer, but you might look into manipulating the gain control on the microphone either on the laptop or on the headset (if possible).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The audio cable does support microphone input. But yes, you're right, the headphones turn off when connected by the audio cable, so they can be used when they run out of battery.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem isn't that you have "Listen to this device" checked under the microphone device then try this:

Under Sound settings, click on Sound Control Panel.

Under the "Playback" tab find the device you're hearing audio through, click it and open properties.

In this menu click on the "Levels" tab. At the top you should have something like "Play Control", but there may also be a list of input devices - make sure all of these are muted or zeroed out.